# How I would I break a total count query into intervals?

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

For example, if I did a normal count query like:

```
select status, count(*)
from customers
group by status
```

and get the result

```
status   count
-----------------
open     1200
closed   1002
```

but I want the count to be split into intervals of 500 so I would get a result returned like this

```
status   count
----------------
open     500
open     500
open     200
closed   500
closed   500
closed   2
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I have to ask... "Why"?

Comment: This screams of something that belongs in the [presentation layer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Presentation_layer) and not as part of the query itself.

Answer (score 2):

You *could* potentially do this using `ROW_NUMBER`.

I'd just advise to steer away from this whole thing, as it's not particularly useful....

If you were to do this, make sure you replace the `<some_id>` with the Customer ID or similar...

```
SELECT status, count(*)
FROM
(
  SELECT 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY status ORDER BY <some_id> ASC) rnum,
    status
  FROM customers
) weirdness
GROUP BY status, (rnum-1)/500;
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work, and should be faster than recursion.

```
;with cte as(
select status, [count] = count(*)
from customers
group by status),

E1(N) AS (select 1 from (values (1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1))dt(n)),
E2(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM E1 a, E1 b), --10E+2 or 100 rows
E4(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM E2 a, E2 b), --10E+4 or 10,000 rows max
cteTally(N) AS 
(
    SELECT  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) FROM E4
)

select
    [status]
    ,[count] = 500
from
    cte t
inner join
    cteTally tally on
    tally.N <= (t.[count] / 500)

union all

select 
    [status]
    ,[count] % 500
from 
    cte
where
    [count] % 500 != 0
order by
    [status] desc, [count] desc
```

**[ONLINE DEMO](http://rextester.com/CYT29740)**

Answer (score 0):

with recursive cte

```
declare @T table (status varchar(10), cnt int);
insert into @T values ('open', 1200), ('closed', 1002);
declare @size int = 200;
--select * 
--from @T;
with cte as
( select t.status, @size as size,                                     t.cnt as rem
  from @T t 
  union all 
  select c.status, case when @size >= c.rem - @size then c.rem - @size else @size end,  c.rem - @size
  from cte c
  join @T t 
    on t.status = c.status 
  where c.rem > @size
)
select * 
from cte 
order by cte.status, cte.rem desc
```